# Javascript library for clickable bar chart?

Tags: javascript, charts

I need a Javascript charting tool to build a bar chart that allows me to click on a chart bar and get another chart (in a popup or below the first chart).
What I need is a bar chart that fires an event giving me some kind of id of the column that has been clicked.

**Dettails**

The data for the first chart should be loaded with ajax when the page loads and the data for the second chart should be loaded when you click on one of the columns.

an example:
A graph with one bar for March and one bar for April,
when you click on the March bar you get a second graph (below or in a pop up) with two bars: one for the 12/03/2011 and the other for the 23/03/2011.

Total expenses:
March 1200
April 300

Total expenses for March:
12/03/2011 1000
23/03/2011 200

Total expenses for April:
16/04/2011 10
21/04/2011 290

Answer (score 5):

Yet another option, if you are already using jQuery: [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/).

Graph Types:
[image: flot graph type example]

Interaction:
[image: flot interaction example]

Click the images to see the actual demo.

Answer (score 2):

[Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) allows custom "click" handlers for individual points or entire series.

Comment: I hope Highcharts library is commercial. It is free for personal or non-profit projects.

Answer (score 2):

[D3.js](http://d3js.org/) is very impressive and renders beautiful charts. Check out their many nice examples on the website:

[image]

It is free and ships with a BSD license

Answer (score 1):

Checkout http://www.jqplot.com/

It doesn't do all that you need out of the box, but if you extend the Cursor class I think you can get the functionality you've been looking for.

http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-cursor-js.html#$.jqplot.Cursor

Comment: jqplot has built-in click handling now: http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/barTest.html

Answer (score 1):

See [gRaphaël](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) - scalable vector charts that work in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera and even Internet Explorer 6+.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The Raphaël looks pretty slick.

Answer (score 0):

[Flotr2](http://www.humblesoftware.com/flotr2) is a substantially enhanced fork of Flot.